# How can I make an lowercase e show up gradually, from center to bottom?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, circularreveal, loading-animation

For a little context: the company I work for has a lowercase e as symbol. So I wanted to make a loading icon where this e is gradually being shown. Starting in the center, then to the right and finally completing the circle. (Something like in the below gif)

[image: Figma animation of what I want]

Thanks to all

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to show some code and your attempt. Also take the [tour].

Comment: If it’s a logo I imagine it’s a very specific shape, not just any font’s lowercase E. How is the e normally drawn, is it an SVG or just eg. a png?

Comment: I want to do this with an SVG, but I'm not sure that matters? What I had planned was making a box with the same background-colour over the logo. The animation would make this box transparent. But if there's an easier way, please be my guest

Answer (score 1):

### create the SVG markup for the loading icon

I used [This source](https://tablericons.com/) for E letter svg

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-letter-e" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2c3e50" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
    <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M17 4h-10v16h10" />
    <path d="M7 12l8 0" />
  </svg>
```

### use CSS animations to gradually show the "e" symbol in the loading icon

I defined a keyframe animation named `fillE` that gradually increases the opacity and scale of the "e" letter to give the loading effect

```
@keyframes fillE {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

path {
  animation: fillE 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

I hope that is what you looking for.

```css
@keyframes fillE {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

path {
  animation: fillE 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-letter-e" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#2c3e50" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M17 4h-10v16h10" />
  <path d="M7 12l8 0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. I added an gif which would help the explanation a bit better, I think

Comment: This nowhere near fulfills the initial criteria which include the requirement to draw a lowercase e from the center to the bottom right.